# sorting with assembly out of range error

Tags: assembly, mips, bubble-sort

I am trying to implement a bubble sort in assembly and I am getting an out of range error in line starred of the code below. I cannot figure out how to fix this. I was hoping someone could take a look and see where the error can be corrected.

```
.data
    vector: .word 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8
    size: .word 10
.text
main:
    li $v0, 4 # enables syscall to load address of string
    la $a0, vector # pass the address of array (base of array) in $a0
    addi $a1, $zero, 10 # pass the array size in $a1
    jal sort
    la $a0, vector
    addi $a1, $zero, 10 # pass the array size in $a1
    jal print_array
    li $v0, 10
    syscall
print_array:
    addi $sp, $sp, -4 # make room for 1 word on the stack
    sw $s0, 0($sp) # save $s0 onto the stack
    addi $t0, $zero, 0# initialize the array loop iterator $t0
    addi $t1, $a0, 0 # save $a0, holding array base, into $t1
    # as it will get overwritten by the print utility
loop:
    beq $t0, $a1, end # test if iterator $t0 is equal to array size $a1
    lw $a0, 0($t1) # bring array contents at $t1 into argument $a0
    li $v0, 1 # enable printing
    syscall # print what's in $a0
    addi $t0, $t0, 1 # increment array iterator
    addi $t1, $t1, 4 # increment address in memory by 1 word
    lw $s0, 0($sp)
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    j loop
end:
    jr $ra
sort:
    move $t9, $v0  # t9=Address of string
    lw $t1, size   # $t1 = size
    li $t0, 0      # $t0 = 0 (i)

loop1:
    beq $t1, $t0, exit  # if $t0 == size, exit
    addi $t4, $t0, -1  # $t4(J) = counter-1

loop2:
    bltz $t4, exit2   # j < 0
    mul $t5, $t4, 2   # $t5 = 2 * j

    add $t5, $t9, $t5 # $t5 = a[2j]

    **lb $t2, 0($t5)   # $t2 = a[j]** ##error here
    lb $t3, 1($t5)   # $t3 = a[j+1]
    ble $t3, $t2, else # a[j+1] >= a[j]
    j swap

else:
    addi $t4, $t4, -1   # --j
    j loop2

exit: 
    move $v0, $t9  #Return $t9 (sorted string)
    jr $ra

exit2:
    addi $t0, $t0, 1   # ++i
    j loop1

swap: 
    sb $t3, 2($t5)
    sb $t2, 1($t5)
    j loop2
```

Comment: Use a debugger to single step the code and see where it goes wrong. That said, initially `$t0` is zero so `$t4` is going to be `0xffffffff` which eventually gives a bad address in `$t5`.

Comment: @Jester I am using an emulator and would not know where to start

Comment: You didn't tell which one but for example spim supports single stepping.

Comment: @Jester I am using mars

Comment: Mars also supports single-stepping through the code.